# Не могу понять причину ошибки SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\E'

Tags: python, pandas, pylance

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as datetime


df = pd.read_csv('C:\EURUSD.csv')
df.head()

df.sort_values('Date', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df.head()

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

При запуске возникает следующая ошибка

**<>:11: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\E'**

Ранее код работал без каких либо проблем, не могу понять какие изменения вызвали ошибку

Версия Python 3.12.2
Версия Pandas 2.2.1

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, полный `traceback` ошибки, и что вы сами предприняли для её исправления? https://python-scripts.com/python-traceback

Comment: ну попробуйте `pd.read_csv('C:\EURUSD.csv')` заменить на `pd.read_csv('C:\\EURUSD.csv')`

Comment: Заработало, не могу понять, что вызвало изменение синтаксиса, если с одним слешем работало

Comment: Либо используйте raw string `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\EURUSD.csv')` У меня и ваш код не ругается, возможно, это зависит от версии питона.